# How to upload a file directly from another URL?

Tags: java, http

Say I have an image file that is located in http://a.com/example.jpg

Then I have a network storage called http://b.com/

Using java, how can I move example.jpg directly to b.com?(Kind of like P2P??)

### EDIT

I think I should explain a little bit more.

I want to move file example.jpg to b.com without downloading the file.

Normal approach will be

1. Open connection to a.com
2. Download example.jpg to my computer (either memory or disk)
3. Open a new connection to b.com
4. Upload the example.jpg to b.com

However, I think this involves unnecessary work.

What I want is this

1. Open connection to b.com
2. Without opening connection to a.com, upload example.jpg directly to b.com (I think this is the part where I thought of P2P)

Is there any way that I can do this?

Comment: Do you just need java http downloading libraries or this question is in something very specific?

Comment: @msangel Something very specific. I just edited my question with more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general way to do what you ask merely with HTTP. You would have to have specific support for such operations on the server hosting your network storage, such that you can request it to download URLs directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image using HttpClient from `a.com` and then upload it to `b.com`. How do you upload it `b.com` depends on what you have there.

To be able to do this without downloading the file you will need specific support on `b.com`. That specific support will be a service on `b.com` where you send a "download" request and the server will download the file itself from `a.com`.

Comment: Sorry if my question was vague. Please see my edited question.